# Expected time for the flower snark graph

Tags: probability, graph-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation

I know that the expected time for a random walk to visit all vertices of a complete graph is, $$\mathrm E(G)= (n-1)(1+(1/2)+(1/3)+...+(1/n-1).$$ But what would be the expected time for a random walk to visit all vertices in a flower snark graph which is a cubic regular graph?